# Pages which are set to never update

Tags: sitemap, change-frequency

I have a website with a blog. I sometimes update the posts but they usually do not change much. In any case, the do not have a periodic update cycle. So, in the sitemap I use that tag:

```
<changefreq>never</changefreq>
```

Now, I tried OnPage a software to detect errors in the site. It says "Pages which are set to never update 92 errors". These are all my posts. So, it considers changefreq never as an error, I suppose.

What is the correct changefreq for a blog post?

Comment: Google does not need a sitemap nor does it respect configurations because the vast majority of sites don't set a changefreq or worse they set it low and don't do regular updates to the page. Search engines are able to estimate and establish when a page is likely to be updated without a sitemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Simon has already stated in comments, Googlebot probably does not pay much attention to the `<changefreq>` property in the XML sitemap when deciding how often to crawl a URL.

> Pages which are set to never update 92 errors

But it is not strictly an *error* to set this to "never". However, it may not be the best option in this case.

As [sitemaps.org](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#changefreqdef) notes:

> The value "never" should be used to describe **archived URLs**.

An archived URL should literally *never* change. A page that is "sometimes" updated, even though it may not change much, is not really an *archived* document.

A value of "yearly" (or even "monthly") might be more appropriate. Note that these values are relative. "yearly" doesn't necessarily mean *once a year*, but rather *less frequently than once a month*. It's a very approximate time frame.

Or, omit the `<changefreq>` entirely.